# How to use nginx's host overwrite logstash's host information when send it by filebeat?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, logstash, host, filebeat

Now using filebeat and logstash sending nginx's json log on k8s.

The nginx's configuration likes

nginx.conf

```
http {
    log_format bucket escape=json
    '{'
        '"request_id": "$request_id",'
        '"method": "$request_method",'
        '"status": "$status",'
        '"forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for",'
        '"host": "$host",'
        '"url": "$request_uri",'
        '"referer": "$http_referer",'
        '"remote_ip": "$remote_addr",'
        '"server_ip": "$server_addr",'
        '"user_agent": "$http_user_agent",'
    '}';
}

server {
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.json  bucket;
}
```

Filebeat's configuration:

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.shutdown_timeout: 5s

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /var/log/nginx/access.json*
    exclude_files: ['\.gz$']
    tags: ["access"]

processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: true
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: false

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash.default.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
```

Here `overwirte_keys` is true so it should overwrite metadata, right?

Logstash's configuration:

logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  if "access" in [tags] {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "[@metadata][tags]" => "%{tags}" }
      remove_field => [
        "agent",
        "event",
        "service",
        "log",
        "input",
        "fileset",
        "ecs",
        "container",
        "kubernetes",
        "@timestamp",
        "@version",
        "message",
        "tags"
      ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  if "access" in [@metadata][tags] {
    google_cloud_storage {
      bucket => "nginx_logs"
      json_key_file => "/secrets/service_account/credentials.json"
      temp_directory => "/tmp/nginx_logs"
      log_file_prefix => "logstash_nginx_logs"
      max_file_size_kbytes => 1024
      output_format => "json"
      date_pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00"
      flush_interval_secs => 2
      gzip => false
      gzip_content_encoding => false
      uploader_interval_secs => 60
      include_uuid => true
      include_hostname => true
    }
  }
}
```

It works well at the beginning. The log data has been generated to json files as:

```
{"user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBDV/iPhone13,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/14.2.1;FBSS/3;FBID/phone;FBLC/ja_JP;FBOP/5]","forwarded_for":"1.2.3.4","host":"api.mysite.com","method":"OPTIONS","request_id":"0127054b954fe4973852e1886130a6ca","referer":"https://www.world.com/","remote_ip":"2.3.4.5","server_ip":"3.4.5.6","status":"204","url":"/api/v1/post"}
```

But recently, this data occurred:

```
{"user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBDV/iPhone13,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/14.2.1;FBSS/3;FBID/phone;FBLC/ja_JP;FBOP/5]","forwarded_for":"1.2.3.4","host":"api.mysite.com","method":"OPTIONS","request_id":"0127054b954fe4973852e1886130a6ca","referer":"https://www.world.com/","remote_ip":"2.3.4.5","server_ip":"3.4.5.6","status":"204","url":"/api/v1/post"}
{"host":{"name":"filebeat-adio3"}}
{"host":{"name":"filebeat-adio3"}}
{"host":{"name":"filebeat-adio3"}}
```

This is not a regular data. It looks like filebeat server's `host` metadata has been sent. But why? Is it a filebeat's mistake or logstash's?
Is there an another good way to filter this host data to ensure to be sent without conflict with fb/logstash's metadata?

Comment: Is `{"host":{"name":"filebeat-adio3"}}` the only and full content of the document or is there more information? If yes, can you share it in full?

Comment: `{"host":{"name":"filebeat-adio3"}}` is the only content sometimes. I updated my question.

Comment: So just to be clear, that content can be found in `/var/log/nginx/access.json`?

Comment: It's difficult to find the old files about nginx since its log rotation is one week. But it seems the issue happened after we deployed new feature last week. At that time, it was possible something went wrong(but not sure if it was nginx's data or fb/logstash's). These days this kind of data didn't happen again.

Comment: Ok, feel free to update this thread if this happens again